# Error getting persistentStoreCoordinator from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm developing an iOS 7+ app whose data is requested to RESTful services. When app launches, I perform several asynchronous services requests, and sometimes I get a `Core Data` error when I receive the response of one of them and I want to create and save the objects with the information I have received.

Since I receive the service's responses asynchronously, for each response I use a temporary `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and perform the insertions in a separated thread, like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(kDataUpdateQueue, NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *mainThreadContextPSC = [self.context persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [tmpContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:mainThreadContextPSC];

        @try {
            // Objects insertion in tmpContext

            [tmpContext save:nil];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Notify end
            });
        }
        @catch (NSException *ex) {
           NSLog(@"exception: %@", [ex description]);
        }
    });
}
```

I usually run the app directly in an iOS 8 device, and sometimes I get an error in the Xcode's debug area like this:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x188c7190 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x18969600 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134080.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.}, {
NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 134080.)\" UserInfo=0x189695e0 {NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice}";}
```

This is thrown in `AppDelegate`'s `persistentStoreCoordinator` getter, when the line `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *mainThreadContextPSC = [self.context persistentStoreCoordinator];` is reached, and `self.context` is:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
return appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

As I said, not always get this error, and I get it even running the app for the first time and then no previous Core Data files exist... I find this weird, why could be this happening?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** If I add this:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
   @synchronized(self) {
      // Rest of the code provided by default
   }
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
   @synchronized(self) {
      // Rest of the code provided by default
   }
}
```

It looks like I don't get that error log anymore. Could this be the solution, or am I just transferring/delaying the problem?

Thanks again

Comment: Can you add the code for your app delegate's `persistentStoreCoordinator` getter method?

Comment: @TomHarrington It is the code already provided when you create the Xcode's project with Core Data enabled, I haven't made any changes there... should I handle concurrency within AppDelegate's Core data related methods?

Comment: OK thanks. Next, is that the entire error message shown in Xcode? Specifically, is there anything in Xcode's console that mentions *"The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"*?

Comment: @TomHarrington sorry for the late reply... no, I'm not getting such log